# Sharepoint online office 365 list items created by asp.net form submit button

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a question regarding SharePoint Online hosted on Office 365.

1. I have an ASP.NET form with three fields and a Submit button. The fields are: `Name`, `lastname`, and `display name`.
2. I have a custom list on a SharePoint Online site with the same fields: `Name`, `lastname`, and `display name`.

I want to save the data to the SharePoint list when a user fills the form and clicks the submit button.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can update a list item on SharePoint Online using the Client Side Object Model:

```
using(ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
 clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,password);
                SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
                ListItem oListItem = oList.Items.GetById(3);

                oListItem["Title"] = "My Updated Title.";

                oListItem.Update();

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
}
```

For creating a new item, use the following code:

```
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// We are just creating a regular list item, so we don't need to 
// set any properties. If we wanted to create a new folder, for 
// example, we would have to set properties such as 
// UnderlyingObjectType to FileSystemObjectType.Folder. 
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation(); 
ListItem newItem = announcementsList.Items.Add(itemCreateInfo); 
newItem["Title"] = "My New Item!"; 
newItem["Body"] = "Hello World!"; 
newItem.Update();
```

Comment: It gives me an error on context.web.lists. What do I need to import or "using" to make this work?